# Combinatorial data in xUnit.NET?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit, mbunit

I'm migrating from MbUnit to xUnit, and I'm trying to locate the equivalent attributes (or approach) to MbUnit's `[CombinatorialJoin]` and `[Column]`.

For example, when testing common  behavior of a function with multiple boolean parameters, `[Column]` makes it very easy to test the permutations:

```
public void TestMethodWithTooManyOptions([Column(true, false)] bool dispose,
                                        [Column(true, false)] bool useDestinationStream,
                                        [Column(true, false)] bool useCorruptedSource,
                                        [Column(true, false)] bool loadTwice,
                                        [Column(true, false)] bool useSourceStream) {
```

`[CombinatorialJoin]`, `[SequentialJoin]`, `[PairwiseJoin]` affect how columns (or rows) are permuted.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing now. Did you ever come up with a suitable solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is perhaps a correct response...

https://github.com/AArnott/Xunit.Combinatorial

Answer (score 1):

If you use ApprovalTests, you can create an xUnit.net Fact and the CombinationApprovals.VerifyAllCombinations method to run combinatorial tests.

It's not the same as using an attribute, but it's the best solution I have found in xUnit.